# Embed a Google Street View image into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to embed a Google Street View into Excel. I found this [link](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/map--street-view-api.html) which has the below code. Doesn't really work at all for me, and looking for some help to get started. Clearly I need to set up variables for the lookups of the URL of street view. But I've never inserted an image through VBA, looking for some guidance.

```
Sub GoogleStaticStreetView(oShape As Shape, _
                        sAddress As String, _
                        lHeading As Long, _
                        Optional lHeight As Long = 512, _
                        Optional lWidth As Long = 512)

    'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/

    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sMapsURL As String

    On Error GoTo RETURN_FALSE

    If bRunMode Then On Error Resume Next 'Error if quota exceeded

    If Len(sAddress) > 0 Then
        'URL-Escaped addresses
        sAddress = Replace(sAddress, " ", "+")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sURL = _
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?" & _
    "&location=" & sAddress & _
    "&size=" & lWidth & "x" & lHeight & _
    "&heading=" & lHeading & _
    "&sensor=false"

    sMapsURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" & _
    sAddress & "&t=m&layer=c&panoid=0" & _
    "&cbp=12," & lHeading & ",,0,4.18"

    oShape.Fill.UserPicture sURL
    oShape.AlternativeText = sMapsURL

    Exit Sub

RETURN_FALSE:

End Sub

Sub GoogleStaticMap(oShape As Shape, _
                    sAddress As String, _
                    Optional sMapType As String = "roadmap", _
                    Optional lZoom As Long = 12, _
                    Optional lHeight As Long = 512, _
                    Optional lWidth As Long = 512)

    'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sMapsURL As String
    Dim sMapTypeURL As String

    On Error GoTo RETURN_FALSE

    ' Google Maps Parameters '&t=m' = roadmap, '&t=k' = satellite
    sMapTypeURL = "m"
    If sMapType = "satellite" Then
        sMapTypeURL = "k"
    End If

    If bRunMode Then On Error Resume Next 'Error if quota exceeded

    If Len(sAddress) > 0 Then
        'URL-Escaped addresses
        sAddress = Replace(sAddress, " ", "+")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sURL = _
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" & _
    sAddress & "," & _
    "&maptype=" & sMapType & _
    "&markers=color:green%7Clabel:%7C" & sAddress & _
    "&zoom=" & lZoom & _
    "&size=" & lWidth & "x" & lHeight & _
    "&sensor=false" & _
    "&scale=1"

    sMapsURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" & _
    sAddress & _
    "&z=" & lZoom & _
    "&t=" & sMapTypeURL

    oShape.Fill.UserPicture sURL
    oShape.AlternativeText = sMapsURL

    Exit Sub

RETURN_FALSE:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that code to work by adding this line to the other Dims in GoogleStaticStreetView:

```
Dim bRunMode As Boolean
```

Then running this module:

```
Sub makeThisCodeWork()
    GoogleStaticStreetView Sheets(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 512, 512), "GooglePlex, CA 94043", 100
    Debug.Assert False
    Sheets(1).Shapes.Delete
End Sub
```

This just creates a rectangle shape object to use as a container, then it lets the code paste the image in.

It will pause execution when it gets to `debug.assert false`, and then it will delete all shapes on the sheet so you can clean run it again. You'll have to play with the address and the heading variables to get what you want though.

I didn't try to run the other module, because that is for returning maps, and you just said StreetView :)

Hope this helps - let me know if you want me to be more verbose/explain what is going on here.

Comment: Wonderful! My rep isn't 15 to upvote you yet. The second it is I will give you the props you deserve! 
One followup question :
The Sheets(1). Shapes.Delete  is kicking an error. I tried Sheet.Sheet1.Shapes.Delete but it didn't like that much either. Shouldn't we identify which sheet we're clearing images from?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, try activesheet instead of sheets(1)

Comment: Using this worked really well :

 Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Shp.Delete
Next Shp